# Summing a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Code:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        sum += ? ;
```

What is better?

```
sum += a[i][j] or
sum += a[j][i]
```

And why?

Comment: What language? (I'm guessing C?)

Comment: You don't seem to understand how 2D arrays work. a[n] means "the array indexed by n" and a[n][m] means "the value indexed at position m of the array indexed at n", so unless we're talking about some specific case, these are not interchangeable.

Comment: @David Robinson.Yes. but,is There a difference for what language you use?

Comment: I know how it works, I also know for different n*m matrices. You get different performance. Just want to know in terms of caching

Comment: a[i][j], probably, due to spatial locality.

Comment: @GuillermoRenéRamírez: No, they are interchangable (in terms of function, not performance) in the code above, since all you are doing is summing a two-dimensional array and it doesn't matter what order you are doing them in.

Comment: @Guillermo René Ramírez. Thank you that is the answer I was looking for... Due to "spatial locality"

Comment: You will get more cache misses if you say a[j][i] instead of a[i][j], because the address of a[0][0] is closer to a[0][1], than to [1][0]. please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you have a squared array (number of columns = number of rows), there is no difference in running time/result.

```
sum+=a[i][j];
```

Ex.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

sum= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9;
```

This one makes the sum by starting with the first row and adding every number on it to the sum and just after it goes to the next row.

sum+=a[j][i];

Ex.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

sum= 1 + 4 + 7 + 2 + 5 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 9;
```

On the other hand this one takes the sum of every element on a column and just after that it moves to the next column.

If you don't have the same number of rows and columns, you would have to edit a little the for syntax.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)     // n = number of rows
  for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)   // m = number of columns
     sum += a[i][j];
```

Of course here you can invert the fors, and/or use sum+a[i][j]; the final result will be the same but the sum will be created in another way.

Edit due to new information:

Informed myself a little about the time complexity and there is actually a small time difference due to the cache.Accessing data memory which are close together is faster than ones that are far apart so a[i][j] would be better than a[j][i].

In order to see the difference on those you would need to use a huge n as the size of the array.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I Like your edit which answers my question :D

Answer (score 1):

There really is no difference as far as what is better. If you care about the total sum of the matrix (e.g. 2 dimensional array), it should not matter. You will get the same sum in the end. If we assume that you use "i" to scan through the rows, and "j" to scan through the columns then if you do "sum += a[i][j]", you will get the sum "one row at a time", if you do "sum += a[j][i]", then it will be one column at a time.

So if you don't care about the intermediary sub-sums but the total sum is what you care about, there is no right or wrong way or better or worse way. The "sum += a[i][j]" though is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, when working with multidimensionalities, I try to stay alphabetical for my own sanity. I.E:

```
sum += a[i][j][k]
```

Comment: Makes sense but there is still a difference in performance. That is how I did it always. But you must also keep in mind the performance of a program